# Error deploying CXF web service client application to weblogic 9.2

Tags: cxf, weblogic9.x

Why do I see this when deploying CXF web service client application to weblogic 9.2

```
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: null
-&gt;&gt;  350 | newInstance0   in java.lang.Class
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    303 | newInstance    in     &#39;&#39;
|     36 | newInstance .  in javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder
|     95 | find           in     &#39;&#39;
|     82 | provider . . . in javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
|     56 | &lt;init&gt;         in javax.xml.ws.Service
```

Running with WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM Version 1.5.0_10-b03

The deployment has jaxws-rt-2.1.3.jar with com/sun/xml/ws/spi/ProviderImpl.class
The deployment has cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.1.3.jar with  org/apache/cxf/jaxws/spi/ProviderImpl

I found this issue when these dependencies were missing, but they are not missing in this case.

I do deploy the war with WEB-INF/weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <weblogic-web-app
        xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 
        http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two jars in the application WEB-INF that were not compatible as they both implement classes

```
javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder
javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
javax.xml.ws.Service
```

The two conflicting jar were

```
jaxws-api-2.1.jar
geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.0.jar
```

I removed the jaxws-api-2.1.jar and was able to get past the issue.